# Replace current line with filtered lines

Tags: global-command

For example, to replace current line with all lines starting with '# ' , I use

```
:.! grep '^\# ' %
```

I know about the `:g` command that can filter lines to perform operations like

```
:g/call/d
:g/cat/ s/animal/mammal/g
:.,+20 g/^# / normal >>
```

But I am not able to figure out a way to just paste the filtered lines.

And how to use inbuilt help in this case?

`:h :g` gives an overview, how to find details on using commands like `:g/call/d`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do so, it gives nearly what you want, so you may be able to build your proper solution on that.

## tl;dr

set a mark on the line to copy to with `ma` and run

```
:g/C/t'a-
```

## decomposition

First of you can use the `g` command here, it filters lines matching a pattern. Then you can use the `t` command, which copy a line.

Let say you have the following file (`A` is just noise):

```
A
A
To replace
A
A
C 1
A
A
C 2
A
A
```

You can do

```
:g/C/t.
```

This will duplicate the lines matching `C`, because `.` reference the current line.

So if you want to duplicate the line at the current position, set a mark and use the command again:

```
ma
:g/C/t'a
```

You will have the following result:

```
A
A
To replace
C 2
C 1
A
A
C 1
A
A
C 2
A
A
```

Nearly there! You can add a `-` to the address of the paste to achieve the paste in the correct order:

```
:g/C/t'a-
```

Will produce:

```
A
A
C 1
C 2
To replace
A
A
C 1
A
A
C 2
A
A
```

Now you can delete the "To replace" line if you want.

**Note:** you can use the absolute line number instead of a mark if you want, i.e. `:g/C/t12`.

### Regarding the help:

You already know about the `:h :g` that gives you the information that `g` takes an Ex command to perform action. So you might want to search for a command that copy.

`:copy` exists and can be abbreviated by `:t`. Both take an address to copy to.

`:h {address}` gives you want you need.

Comment: thanks, lot of info here, will go through and ask further questions if needed

Comment: so, I tried these... `ddma:g/^# /t'a-` is the best fit I could do.. `'a-` also gives the lines in same order as occurs in file, which I needed..  `:h :t` conveniently has help on `:m` as next item, so I now know how to move the filtered lines :)

Comment: Nice, let me add this to the answer!

Answer (score 2):

There's `copy`, or `t` for short: `:g/^#/t3` where 3 is the line you're currently on. You'd still need to delete the line itself afterwards (or before... when using `dd` before the global call, you can use `:g/^#/t2` to exactly have your replace). Of course, you could also define a function and bind that to a key to have it all in one step, but imho that's overkill in this case.

Looking for docs, `:h global` will tell you about the usage of `:g`, which in turn refers to the `[cmd]` part. You can find the ex commands with `:h ex-cmd`. Also see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the ex command output to any register and then paste the register's content in a line.

```
   :redir @a
   :g/^#/p
   :redir END
```

Now, the lines starting with # are present in a register.
You can go to that line and press dd and then paste it using "ap
The content is pasted in the line. I have taken 'a' register.

Comment: thanks for alternate solution, new command to learn.. I'll wait for any other answers.. plus this one requires lot of steps in which case I can as well stick to `grep`